# Remote MYSQL using phpmyadmin connection is very slow

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

First off the reason I am doing this is since I'm using shared hosting with HostGator they do not keep the phpmyadmin install up to date.  Matter of face at the time of this post phpmyadmin reports -> "Version information: 3.5.5, latest stable version: 4.1.14"  So it's lacking in a lot of bug fixes and improvements.

I went and got the latest and greatest version of phpmyadmin and installed it on my hosting.  I followed HostGators instructions on whitelisting my IP as this is how they get around giving the database(s) remote access.  I also opened port 3306 on my firewall.

When I connect is so slow!  Getting the table structures I can go get coffee and it'll be just coming up.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'HG FTSC';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '**********_mgmt';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db'] = array('**********_ftsc');
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = false;
```

It shouldn't be slow if I'm doing this right on the actual server.  But it is!

I appreciate the help!

- Dave

Comment: `if I'm doing this right on the actual server` be more precise please

Comment: its always faster to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` but its most likely not your problem, unless you make coffee in under a couple of seconds?

Comment: @Sebas on the hosting server. I gave it the IP HostGator provided.

Comment: @LozCherone I did this when I tried accessing it from my local install at home instead of on the hosting services space.  Same thing used the IP given from cPanel.  Still slow actually it times ok on my PC I probably need to set script execution to longer than 30 seconds.

Comment: but you´re running it not from the server, but from *your* browser. try pinging your server to begin with...

Comment: @Sebas  
`code` C:\Users\Dave>ping 50.87.146.235

Pinging 50.87.146.235 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 50.87.146.235: bytes=32 time=99ms TTL=50
Reply from 50.87.146.235: bytes=32 time=101ms TTL=50
Reply from 50.87.146.235: bytes=32 time=86ms TTL=50
Reply from 50.87.146.235: bytes=32 time=86ms TTL=50
Ping statistics for 50.87.146.235:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 86ms, Maximum = 101ms, Average = 93ms
Ok pings to the hosting server.  
Sorry about my lack of formatting.

Comment: In addition it is easier to show you then to type it.

This screen recording is trying to use phpmyadmin from the PC to the MySQL host at HostGator -> http://youtu.be/TPYsQnja1CI

This screen recording is trying to use phpmyadmin installed on the paid hosting.  It's quicker but still takes alot of time to do simple tasks. -> http://youtu.be/SJuquHp36vs

Recording are in 1080p.  Once you watch you'll see how ridiculously slow it is!

Comment: it might be a firewall problem. Did you try random sql expressions from a php page? Do they render well?

Comment: @Sebas Yes, query still took a long time.  I think the later video where I was trying it on the hosted side that it took a simple query a long time to render results and it showed that it was only mere microseconds when MySQL return the query.  And yes to the first question, I turned off the firewall still got the same problem.

Comment: This has been solved!  It's not a hosting issue or mine.  HostGator intentionally slows the remote connection to databases on shared hosting because people have taken advantage of it.

Their suggestion to do the reverse for testing and host the database locally and put the page on the hosted site and obviously when done either export the database and import it on the hosted site or make the changes to the hosted sites database and change where it's pointed to.

Answer (score 2):

OP has specified in the comments that the issue has been resolved. Just pasting this here so future users don't have to look through the comments (OP if you feel you'd rather post the answer yourself, please do so and accept that one as the answer).

OP said (minor changes for readability):

> This has been solved! It's not a hosting issue or mine. HostGator intentionally slows the remote connection to databases on shared hosting, because people have taken advantage of it. Their suggestion was to do the reverse for testing, and host the database locally. Put the page on the hosted site and, obviously, when done either export the database and import it on the hosted site. You can also make the changes to the hosted sites database and change where it's pointed to.

Comment: Wow. Thanks, this is really helpful service you did here :-)